# Show Hide column and reorder GridJS

Tags: json, gridjs

I configured Gridjs for datatables

is there any solution/ option to  show/hide column for the final user and also reorder the columns?

Thanks

Bye

Comment: This is a good question and should be answered as it is not clear if it is possible to reorder columns.  The documentation does not mention it.  I am having to recreate a grid and rearrange the data for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hide columns by adding something along these lines in my CSS.

```
[data-column-id="DatabaseID"] {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

It's a little hacky but it got the job done since I didn't find anything built into gridjs although you can probably add this into the style property of the setup as well.

Comment: I love this answer. Great stuff. Works perfectly.